# Can you set code to fire when a text message is received?

Tags: iphone

I'm still very new to the iOS SDK. Is it possible to hook into a received text message event? For instance, to display an image whenever a text message is received.

Not having been able to find it in the docs, so I'm assuming no, but wanted to double check before I crossed this off my list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. Not much more to say.